# how to get iota balance via api url?

Tags: node.js, api, bitcoin, iota

I've searched for few days...  to get IOTA Coin balance via api call directly.

They provided us a documentation for that:- 
https://iota.readme.io/reference#getbalances

Comment: Which programming language do you use? There are a lot of libraries with which the balance can be easily requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure what you expect here, either run your own node (thus, the `localhost` reference in the docs) or call a public one...

```
$ curl -s http://iota.bitfinex.com \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-IOTA-API-Version: 1' \
  -d '{"command": "getBalances", "addresses": ["HBBYKAKTILIPVUKFOTSLHGENPTXYBNKXZFQFR9VQFWNBMTQNRVOUKPVPRNBSZVVILMAFBKOTBLGLWLOHQ"], "threshold": 100}' \
  | jq


{
  "balances": [
    "0"
  ],
  "references": [
    "BTJRZDCMYEEQBMGKIGZFDFHQWIWTX9UYUFEOLYIHVVWM9HYRZPOZCKRQFNYDLNGTT9KZHGUTGNSNZ9999"
  ],
  "milestoneIndex": 328554,
  "duration": 160
}
```